# How to make a feed readable by an rss reader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rss

I am looking for a Android compatible Java feed reader class to help create a calendar application for my school's calendar. The feed I was given is located [here](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic) and it is atom based; not RSS 2.0

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/) very good article by IBM should get you going. It covers all the concepts and tech involved... with full code examples and documentation starting on page 4. A project for download as well to build their example. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial, but i was looking for something that could read atom based rss feed like the one I posted a link to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these codes from a project of mine https://github.com/dodyg/AndroidRivers/tree/master/src/com/silverkeytech/android_rivers/syndications

They handle Atom and RSS equally fine.